# Attempting to uninstall Photoshop CS5 produces error. How can I uninstall?

Tags: photoshop-cs5

I had installed Photoshop CS5 on my E: drive but my Program Files are located in C: drive. Everything worked perfectly fine, but then due to a virus attack I formatted my C: drive. And now when I try to launch my PS CS5 from the E: drive this is what happens:

[image]

Now that I decided to uninstall PS.  I don't have it show in control panel>uninstall programs section, CCleaner too doesn't detect it.  Could anyone enlighten me with a solution for uninstalling?   Does the "uninstall program" list show only the programs installed in `C:\program files`?

Comment: Why not do a repair (re)install and then uninstall?

Comment: @techie007 while reinstalling,i should then locate the path exactly to my existing ps path so that the ps uninstaller is available in the control panel list,right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the paths used that point to the uninstaller on your machine were on that C drive where the registry likely was stored on your initial installation. The registry houses this information under **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall**. Since that registry entry no longer exist under the Uninstall Key, you'll need to redo the installation of Photoshop and have it point back to the E drive for its installation path.

Comment: So should i just SHIFT+DELETE the existing Ps E drive installion?

Comment: @Nick_inaw IMO: Might as well, as it's not properly registered with Windows anymore.

Comment: It may be unnecessary to do that, but if the installer won't proceed because of any kind of access denied errors, then you may want to take that course of action, otherwise, just run the installer like you were installing it for the first time and make sure to choose the installation path on the E drive where you want it to install.

Comment: @techie007 will it be a issue if i try reinstalling ps-cs6 in my existing ps-cs5 destination for a repair?

Comment: If you blew away the registry, you're probably not going to "repair" it.  Just delete it and start over.  If you get stuck on specific things come back and post a new question about that specific problem.

Comment: I agree with techie007  about blowing it away if you're going to use a newer version of Photoshop. There isn't a way to do a repair install since your original registry entries will be missing when you redid your Windows installation.